# Prove Fisher's Inequality for a non-trivial 2 - (v, 4, λ) design

Tags: combinatorial-designs

Fisher's Inequality states that if $v\ge k$, then $b\ge v$. In this case $k=4$.

I am still pretty new to designs, and so don't understand things fully yet.
There is a formula for $b$ as follows:

$$b = \frac{\lambda v(v-1)}{k(k-1)}$$

Using this, I reduced the problem to showing that $\lambda(v-1)\ge 12$

I am not sure where to go with this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisher's inequality works under condition $v>k$. So I will assume that also $v>k$ in your case. Since one of the basic arguments leads to equality $vr=bk$, then proving $b\geq v$ is the same as proving $r\geq k$. So in your case it is enough to show that $r\geq 4$, i.e. that each element is contained in 4 or more blocks. Moreover, the second basic equality $r(k-1)=\lambda(v-1)$ in common with $v>k$ imply that $r>\lambda$. 
Now it is enough to play with cases $(r,\lambda)\in\{(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)\}$. 
However, again, using the basic two equalities and $k=4$ we obtain that
$$ b = \frac r4\cdot\left(\frac{3r}{\lambda}+1\right).$$
None of the 3 cases lead to integer $b$, therefore necessarily $r\geq 4$, and we are ready.